# How to remove insets in UILabel in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, autolayout

I have simple label with text D and i use sizeToFit i got height 21.5

But i see padding about 2px

How to remove it?

[image]
[image]

I try layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero - but no effect

Comment: Try setting text to Dj and see if magic happens on the bottom side?

Comment: No changes. Only bottom removed

Comment: Thats because of the font height. I j removed the bottom padding it means that there might be some characters that are taller then D that will reach the top of the labe

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try subclassing the `UILabel` and overriding `drawTextInRect:` with:

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0., 0., 0., 0.))];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 30);
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
CGRect labelFrame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(frame, contentInsets);
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
```